# can i seperate java class files for each pages in viewpager of tab view

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have imported the tabbed activity from android studio.
Under static placeholder fragment i have oncreate view and i have switched cases for each tab and given a seperate layout for each. I want to work in separate java class for each page in tab view. Can i seperate each cases to be in seperate class?

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         int tabNumber= getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
          switch (tabNumber)  {
            case 1: {

                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);


                return rootView;
            }
              case 2: {

                  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);



                  return rootView;
              }
              case 3: {

                  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);




                  return rootView;
              }
```

Comment: Yes you can create different fragment for different tab and manage it easly

Comment: Yes. Just remove the static key from the class declaration and move that fragment class to new file

Comment: can you show me my code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So rishav there is a geItem method which returns variables as super.(  ..... )

just return fragment at this place.

```
@Override
 public Fragment getItem(int i) 
{ Fragment fragment;
 switch(i){ 
case 0: fragment = new MyFragment1(); 
break; 
case 1: fragment = new MyFragment2(); 
break; 
case 2:
 fragment = new MyFragment3(); break; 
default: 
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid section number"); } 
return fragment; }
```

Comment: Yes simple and perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

```
private class DesignDemoPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public DesignDemoPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            //
            if (position == 0) {

                    BaseFragment f = new SalesBlankTab();
                    salesStack.get(AppConstant.SALES_REPORT_TAB).push(f);
                    return f;

            } else if (position == 1) {

                    BaseFragment f = new MemberBlankTab();
                    salesStack.get(AppConstant.MEMBER_ORDER).push(f);
                    return f;

            } else {
                BaseFragment f = new  StockBlankTab();//MemberBlankTab,StockBlankTab
                salesStack.get(AppConstant.STOCK_MANAGEMENT).push(f);
                return f;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return AppConstant.TAB_COUNT;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (from Android Hive):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

for more detail, you can try on this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/